# MySQL date_format( date, '%Y-%m-%d %h') as `day-hour` equivalent in Presto

Tags: mysql, presto, amazon-athena

I have column date column, timestamp data type.

```
      date
'2020-08-05 01:01:24.000'
'2020-08-05 02:02:24.000'
'2020-08-05 02:03:24.000'
```

I want to groupby day-hours.

So In MySQL I would do this by

```
    select date_format( date, '%Y-%m-%d %h') as `day-hour`
      from table 
  group by date_format( date, '%Y-%m-%d %h');
```

which would output:

```
   day-hour
2020-08-05 01
2020-08-05 02
```

How can I do this in Presto?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can cast those strings to `TIMESTAMP` and use [`date_trunc`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html?highlight=date_trunc#date_trunc) to truncate the timestamps to hours:

```
WITH data(x) AS (VALUES
    '2020-08-05 01:01:24.000',
    '2020-08-05 02:02:24.000',
    '2020-08-05 02:03:24.000')
SELECT date_trunc('hour', CAST(x AS TIMESTAMP))
FROM data
GROUP BY 1
```

```
          _col0
-------------------------
 2020-08-05 01:00:00.000
 2020-08-05 02:00:00.000
(2 rows)
```

Comment: Perfect! Also seems more cleaner! Thanks